What is the correct way to replace this switch?
I have a touch dimmer switch (press on the switch to turn on, keep pressing to dim/rise) in a bathroom that my family would like replaced (whenever the shower is too steamy it causes the lights to dim and rise automatically and then eventually just blink on and off). The wiring is not straightforward so I would like to know how to wire this correctly using a traditional switch (if possible).
the confusing bit is it looks like I have a common wire (nutted with the red wire going into the switch) and then two travelers (?) together with the black wire going into the switch. whites (neutral?) are all bound up together behind the switch. ground is self-evident.
i’m not sure how to move forward with this with a traditional flip switch. i have a leftover 3-way switch from another project and i was going to just use that but with this wiring i’m not au

Was there a nut on the ground wires before?

yes. i'd removed it before getting confused which was when i took the picture

Those are not travelers, they are both hot: one from the power source and one going in to another switch (or outlet) in the circuit.
Do not use a 3-way switch.
You need to basically keep the wiring the same way. To connect the two wires to a screw terminal, use a short piece of wire (a pigtail) between the wire nut and the screw terminal. The wire connect to red is the load, connect it to the other screw terminal. Connect the bare wire to the ground screw.
